# Would a Book recommendation Q&A fit the Stackexchange format

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I found a bunch of questions about if book recommendation questions are suitable or unsuitable, if they are suitable or unsuitable on certain Stack Exchange sites and if they should be outright forbidden.

But I haven't found anything about the fact if there should be a dedicated Stack Exchange site about recommending books and getting recommendations.

Why will it fit or not fit the Stack Exchange format?

What are the pros and cons against it?

**Making this clear**: This question is **NOT** about *if* a book recommendation site will work; this is to be determined by Area51 as many did not fail to state.

It **IS** about *if* the StackExchange format *can* work for this type of Q&A or if it *cannot* and the *why* behind these answers.

Comment: You should discuss this on [area51.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because discussions over new site proposals belong on Area51.

Comment: @Servy why not vote to move it to Area51 then instead?

Comment: There's no close option to move questions from here to Area 51.

Answer (score 7):

The biggest con is that Stack Exchange isn't a recommendation engine. Amazon and [goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/) are already really good at recommending books.

Answer (score 2):

New sites can be proposed at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

You can add it and see if it get enough supporters to be launched.

Comment: I might even do that. Still I would like to discuss the pros and cons first. There is no point in proposing a new site if it doesn't fit with SE's format.

Comment: But here is not the place. At Area51 is. If you don't want to propose it then go to the discussion zone of Area51